# Always link the "How to Ask" page from Ask a Question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions

Early on when you ask a question, possibly just the first time, you get presented initially with the ["How to Ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) before you can move on to the Ask a Question page.

Recommend also adding a link to the How to Ask page from Ask a Question, as a reminder and easy way to find that page again if you want to.

Separately, could probably use linking from the FAQ as well.

Comment: +1 I asked the same question in the [chat Jeff had started](http://chat.serverfault.com/transcript/message/17100#17100) about 'How to Ask' on SF.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I now link to this on Stack Overflow, at least. The `/questions/ask` page help sidebar now reads:

> How to Ask
>
> - Is your question about programming?
> - We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
> - Provide details. Write clearly and simply.
> - If your question is about this website, [ask it on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) instead.
>
> [asking help »](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)
> [read the faq »](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

I'm leery of linking this page on other sites yet because they don't have [the How to Ask EULA mode](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) enabled.

Comment: Sweet! That looks great.

Comment: Excellent! Any chance of adding it to the bottom of the "How to Format" box as well? People spend a lot more time with that showing (because they have the question textbox focussed) than the "How to Ask" box (when they have the title textbox focussed).