# How do I ask a question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Can you advise me how to post a question about Excel?
I have tried clicking the "Ask Question" button, but what happens is the following:

- Log in
- Ask Question
- Stackoverflow
- Ask Question

Comment: What happened when you click on Ask Question? Were you redirected to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Should be "Log in --> Ask Question --> Post Your Question"

Comment: If you want to ask about Excel, you're probably better off asking at SuperUser

Comment: @tombull89 Depends on what the question is about. If it's about (for instance) doing interop, then it's suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I guess you ended up on this page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice? If so, read the entire page. When you get to the bottom, check the box in front of *"thanks, I will keep these tips in mind when asking"*. Then click on "proceed".

Comment: @Bart - though he must have got through the same page here (unless it doesn't appear here of course).

Comment: What happened @badp? Code formatting?

Comment: Bad kitty! Bad kitty!

Comment: @hims056 mreeow

Comment: @Chris, [in October 2010](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/): *"For now, these measures are (mostly) only enabled on Stack Overflow, as it’s the only site large enough to have these big city problems at the moment."* And [December 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68216/always-link-the-how-to-ask-page-from-ask-a-question/71628#71628): *"other sites [...] don't have the How to Ask EULA mode enabled"*. (But surely things might have changed.)

Comment: @Arjan - ah. That explains it. The page exists but as you need to register to post a question I couldn't (easily) check whether it appeared for new users.

Comment: @ChrisF I have seen it on beta phase sites.